# Android Studio 2.3.3 activity AppTheme empty list

Tags: android

Recently I have installed **Android Studio 2.3.3** but the activity is not getting render and also whenever I click on `AppTheme`, there is no item in the list and API Version in Editor is also `<null>` .

[image]

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: please have a look to screen shot ... just click on above link please.

Comment: have you try to invalidate and restart studio @ M Haroon

Comment: Well, I have the same Problem on Android Studio 3.0.1 (project was ported from an older Android Studio version).

Answer (score 0):

I am also have your problem in Android Studio 3.0.1 and issue after this steps:

1. Change your App's build.gradle(Module:app) file row of desing:
   for me this =>  `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'`
   to older version like : `implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'`
2. Click sync now and wait to build complete
3. Change to your version of the design to the current version like :
   `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'`
4. Click sync now again
5. After building correct your problem.